# gerar Json através de arquivo txt (Posição) por php

Tags: php, json, txt

Estou com uma dificuldade ao tentar gerar o **Json** usando a base de um arquivo em **txt** por determinadas posições.
Não consegui evoluir o código, pois não sei fazer um explode na posição que eu preciso. Ex:

Tenho o arquivo **teste.txt** que contem os seguintes dados:

```
1001444Denis
1233243Joao
4341233Maria
```

da posição **(1)** a **(4)** eu tenho o **login**

da posição **(5)** a **(7)** eu tenho a **senha**

da posição **(8)** a **(100)** eu tenho o **nome** da pessoa

cada linha fecha exatamente na posição 100

fiz o código abaixo mas não consegui evoluir:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('teste.txt', 'r');
while(!feof($file)){
$content = fgets ($file);
?>
```

Quando dou um `var_dump` ele me retorna a informação completa de cada linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função que você precisa é a `substr`, que retorna parte de uma string.

Então você poderia fazer:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('teste.txt', 'r');
while(!feof($file)){
    $content = fgets ($file);
    $login = substr($content, 0, 4); // Da posição "0" (primeiro caractere), pega 4 caracteres
    $senha = substr($content, 4, 3); // Da posição "4" (quinto caractere), pega 3 caracretes
    $nome = substr($content, 7); // Da posição "7" (oitavo caractere), pega até o fim da linha
}
?>
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Comment: Diego, obrigado pela ajuda. o código funcionou muito bem dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar regex, por exemplo:

```
<?php
     $subject = "abcdef";
     $pattern = '/^def/';
     preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
     print_r($matches);
?>
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => def
            [1] => 0
        )

)
```

No seu caso, você pode tentar recuperar o valor de cada linha do arquivo e separar por regex passando as classes de caracteres.

```
[0-9]{1,4}[0-9]{5,7}[A-z]{8,}
```

Essa Pattern já iria separar login, senha e o nome.

Comment: Jonathan, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. o seu método também funcionou.